# What is a popular, multi-platform, free and open source socket library

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Is there any free open source library (in C/C++) for sockets that is widely used and supports wide range of operating systems (Windows, Unix/Linux, FreeBSD etc). Just like pthreads.

Otherwise the only solution left would be to write socket wrapper for each operating system. Or would writing a wrapper against winsock and GNU C sys/socket.h libraries would be enough?

Wouldn't it be possible that I implement it against the socket library provided with GNU C. GNU C is available for wide range of platforms and my code will work in all those platforms?

Comment: Note that C and C++ will give quite different answers. Just because they're similar doesn't mean you should tag questions with both. If you want C++ libraries, tag it C++ - the C libraries will be rather clumsy compared to a native C++ library.

Comment: I am writing a c++ library, but it'd be ok with me if the implementation is in C. I can use both.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible that I implement it against the socket library provided with GNU C. GNU C is available for wide range of platforms and my code will work in all those platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe both the [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/) and GTK+'s GLib libraries have socket APIs. Since your question is tagged `c` and `c++` I suspect you really want C++-centric answers, but both of these are good as pure C libraries.

Comment: Apache Portable Runtime is a good suggestion. Apache also uses it, so I think it would be stable, scalable and with good performance.
GLib has full support of UNIX but support for windows in partial.

Answer (score 13):

Consider looking at [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)?

Comment: boost.asio is also available as a stand-alone package. http://think-async.com/Asio/

Answer (score 9):

[QT](http://qt.nokia.com/products) if it isn't too big for you. [Boost](http://www.boost.org) has some network code as well. [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) has with wxNet a network library as well. Another lib is [Clanlib](http://www.clanlib.org/docs/clanlib-2.0.0/overview/). And of course [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/)

Answer (score 4):

ACE may Help you !

**This tutorial provides an overview of the ACE OS adaptation layer and the design and use of its C++ Socket wrappers**

[Developing Efficient and Portable Communication Software with ACE and C++](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/tutorials-ace.html)

Comment: If you take a look at ACE, don't get overwhelmed by the size of it.  The core ACE library has easy to use TCP and UDP classes.  The online documentation is pretty much reference.  Get the book "ACE Programmer's Guide" to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Another option you can try is [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/). Poco has a lot more than sockets as well, so if you need other stuff it can provide as well.

Comparing it to other toolkits:

1. Qt has GUI and some very sophisticated features you won't find in Poco, but it's a lot bigger.
2. Boost doesn't have as much as Poco in the way of actual functionality, but it has libraries like reference wrappers, MPL and preprocessor which cannot be found anywhere else.
3. I don't remember ACE very well, but I remember it was very very big in terms of source code and components. ACE seems to be used for very high performance network applications, so it may be overkill. But then again, I'm not too sure.

Just my two cents

Comment: From the list of supported platforms, I cannot find UNIX/Linux. On the other hand they have put more emphasis on embedded platforms.

Comment: Poco's supported platforms? They do support Unix/Linux. It's on the home page at the bottom: Linux; HP-UX; Tru64; Solaris. All these are Unix or Unix-like operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will get very far with a wrapper around Winsock and standard Berkeley sockets. In fact, the differences are so small it's almost possible to do it with `#ifdef` directly in the code.

That is, if you're willing to work at the socket level. If you're after something more abstract, then of course wrapping it gives you a good opportunity to also hide the differences.

In particular, Winsock:

- Requires you to "start it up" by calling `WSAStartup()` before any other socket function
- Does not allow you to use plain old close() on a socket; you must use `closesocket()`
- Requires that you use `WSAGetLastError()` to get the last error, not plain `errno`.

Those are the three major ones off the top of my head, there might be more.

Comment: Why? It's been done dozens of times before and I doubt you can't find an interface you like.

Comment: @Chris: Why what? :) Why work at the socket level? I don't know, sometimes it makes sense, but you still might want to be portable.

Comment: I am thinking of writing a class (abstract if it has to) which will hide the differences. I can derive from that class an implement for winsock and Linux sockets or any other library.
That is if i dont find a small and efficient library.

Comment: @unwind: I cannot comment for Chris, but I'd ask: Why do it yourself if there are so many implementations out there?

Comment: Why wrap it when there is nothing to wrap? BSD socket calls work everywhere.

Comment: @Chris Becke: that was sort of my point, yeah. There are some minor differences on Windows (you can't close() a socket, for instance).

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible that I implement it against the socket library provided with GNU C. GNU C is available for wide range of platforms and my code will work in all those platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Use boost::asio. Very good library. Follow this link 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Answer (score 3):

Some links for you :
[C++ Sockets Library](http://www.alhem.net/Sockets/index.html)
[C++ Socket library - ComPP 1.3](http://cplusplusworld.com/socketlibrary.html)
[SimpleSockets](http://sockets.carrierlabs.com/)
[libmsocket](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kageki/files/libmsocket/)
[Komodia TCP/IP library](http://www.komodia.com/index.php?page=newtools.html)
[STLplus C++ library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlplus/)

Framework
[nitro++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ultima/files/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a very light, C++ only, iostreams-style wrapper around BSD sockets, you could consider [skstream](http://www.worldforge.org/dev/eng/libraries/skstream) - it's simple and works well. Of course, the iostreams interface itself leaves much to be desired. skstream does wrap select and the very low-level socket handling up for you quite nicely, though.

Answer (score -2):

There is only one correct answer here. OpenSSL. Because once you have socket code, youre going to want to make SSL connections too. If you are already working in a particular cross platform framework, OpenSSL bindings might already be avaialable.
I don't think theres much excuse now to not SSL/TLS enable your application from the get-go.

Comment: sorry but we are talking about socket programming, not session layer or security.