# How to send SYN packet using C# or Java

Tags: c#

I want to send SYN packet to a remote host, now the problem is that if I use any of the classes of .NET framework then I cannot to do this; e.g. TCP Client takes Host ip and port number and establishes connection, same is the case with ClientSocket class in java.

I want to control the connection establishment my self; I mean I want to send the connection request (SYN packet) then wait for the  connection reply and then send the packet. I know that it might not be easy without external libraries, so if any one can guide me how to do it in either C# or Java. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than commenting to both answers so far ... raw sockets have been restricted in Windows since XP (countermeasure to malware attacks). Read the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx

Once that's done you can certainly build a raw socket following their rules based on Mat's answer for Java or Ritch's for C#.

It will be heavily restricted access, and very system dependent either way. I'm unaware of a method to complete the 3 way handshake and transmit data across TCP/UDP (though I'd be interested in hearing one).

I thought I should make one quick amendment to this answer. If you don't use winsock and instead use a different TCP stack, you can probably get what you want (but this is still not directly availalbe within the OS). Look at this as an example offering: http://www.komodia.com/tcpip-library-v5-1/ or this previous SO thread [What is a popular, multi-platform, free and open source socket library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587252/what-is-a-popular-multi-platform-free-and-open-source-socket-library)

Comment: + 1Good points. I wasn't aware of the security restrictions. It looks like a filter driver might be the only way to make it happen. I'd venture a guess that the OP would get more out of sniffing traffic, than trying to interact with.

Comment: In case you're interested in the history. This was partly based on response to the code red worm. Steve Gibson from GRC was very public in trying to get MSFT to remove the raw socket cabability in XP. The original article is offline, but this is a good cache: http://www.crime-research.org/library/grcdos.pdf --- and for completeness a rebuttal http://staff.washington.edu/dittrich/misc/ddos/grc-reply.txt

Comment: @iivel - After reading varius stuxnet analysis, that seems like such a simpler time.

Comment: @Ritch - No kidding. Security is my field and I can't even imagine what people will come up with next. As a note, I did post some alternative TCP stack options in the answer. (Komodia has some slick products)

Comment: Hi iivel!!  thnx for ur reply !! ; they were very helpful ; Komodia is not a good option for me cuz it is in C++ i was looking for something in C# or java, i have found a better solution Jpcap (Network library for Java) is perhaps a good option...  with Jpcap u can do anything from sending connection request to making custom packets  and much more.....

Comment: @usama: I don't believe that Jpcap, Winpcap (or any variant of libpcap) have the capability of completing the handshake. Please let me know if you find a way to work around it.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called *raw sockets*. I don't know about C#, but there are libraries in Java that let you do that, e.g. [RockSaw](http://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/). You cannot do it using pure Java as far as I know.

Be warned that on some operating systems (Linux at least), you need administrator privileges to be able to open raw sockets. And there are a bunch of restrictions on Windows. (See that page I linked.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Socket class with a SocketType of raw, and the correct protocol type. I think you want TCP.

```
  var sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```